# ArrayList.GetRange(0,54).ToString() is returning "System.Collections.ArrayList+Range"

Tags: c#, arraylist

54 should be unimportant.

The arrayList is filled during an `ArrayList.AddRange(return_value)`
where `byte[] return_value = (byte[])this.in_buffer.ToArray(typeof(byte))` (and `in_buffer` is type `ArrayList` also filled with `AddRange(byte[] bytes)`)

Why? I didn't write the `typeof(byte)` part. I plan to go read about it now. Do I need to make use of something similar? While writing this, this possibility occurred to me.

Comment: What did you expect to see when you used .ToString()? The default implementation of .ToString() displays the type of the object. In this case, it's displaying the fact that the object is of type ArrayList.Range.

Comment: Also, unless you're stuck using .NET 1.1, you should not use ArrayList at all. Use `List<Object>` if you need a collection that can contain any object, otherwise use `List<T>` where `T` is the type of the object that will be in the collection.

Comment: Your example would be *much* easier to follow if you'd just write it out as a block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList.GetRange` is implemented by returning a subclass of `ArrayList` called `Range`, which is actually nested within `ArrayList`, that's all. `ToString` is just showing that type's name.

What were you expecting?

Comment: A concatenated string of the bytes inside the arrayList; do I need to do that manually?

Answer (score 1):

The ToString method on `System.Object` returns the name of the type by default, so the values of the array are not returned, which I guess you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

System.Collections.ArrayList contains a nested class called Range, which derives from ArrayList. This is the type that is returned by GetRange, but it is exposed as an ArrayList. The `+` part of the returned string indicates a nested type.